# Converting DateTime to string before sending to the database

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have a method that have two DateTime and a int as its parameter e.g:

```
public <list>MethodName(DateTime a, DateTime b, int c)
```

if a user selects Date a then data should be loaded from the database based on that date only, else if a user selects two dates then the data should be loaded from date a to date b. To do this i have to first check if the value in my date field is null or not-null. To do this i did:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime();
DateTime dd = new DateTime();
int i = new int();
```

now I will check if my value is null, for this i have used if loop:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)) {
d=Convert.ToDateTime(a).ToLongDateString()
} same for the parameter b and c...
```

After knowing if its null or not null i can then try retrieving data from the database but i get a error as: 
    String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I am using bootstrap calendar so in my input box i get dd/mm/yyyy using the value from this textbox i am tryng to load data.

Comment: Try `DateTime.ParseExact(a, "dd/MM/yyyy",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: i get error Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles)' has some invalid arguments. What if i convert my return type from DateTime to string? but how would i update this code from DateTime to string?

Comment: I do things like this all the time, but I pass it all into SQL stored procedures. SQL is having a hard time with the string you are sending, so send it as a datetime

Comment: @wruckie if i remove ToLongDateString(); i get same error

Comment: How are you accessing the DB? Put some of that code here also.

Comment: @Dip: have you regognized that i have edited my comment.

Comment: Can you post your code where you are using your query? What about using [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQL server pass date as string formatted to yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: It should be passed as a datetime parameter, not as a string.

Comment: I understand that the datatype of this parameter is DateTime in SQL serve but we can pass it as I have suggested from front-end and it will works fine.